# Using the windows context menu with highlighted items?

Tags: windows, contextmenu

I've written a command-line program that will list and save the names of the files that have been selected.

I am trying to make it work so that when I have selected a group of files, I can run the program from the windows context menu (the window that pops up when you right-click on screen)

However, even though it works through the command-line and when I hover the program with my selected files, when I try to use the context-menu it asks me to select a default application instead.

Here's an image to better explain what I'm getting at:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but, it sounds like you're asking how to associate your file list with a program.  Is that correct?

Comment: I think that's it. The problem is that I don't want to have to do that every single time I use my program. What I mean is, everytime I run it, that window asking for a default application always shows up. I would like my program to run by default but if I do that then it messes with the default program for that file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a file association in Windows.  A file association specifies what program is to be used to open, run, etc. the file.  Have a look [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-file-associations-windows) for an example how to accomplish that.